# Cakephp 3.x bake - get cli options inside templates

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-bake

In Cakephp 3.x when baking e.g. templates for admin I run.

```
 bin/cake bake template Posts --prefix admin
```

This works fine and files are generated successfully, however how inside bake' templates can I check if that `prefix` option is set or not. I need to check that condition if this is for admin to make different output.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell the value is currently not available out of the box, unlike the controller task, the template task doesn't pass the prefix to the view, see

- **https://github.com/cakephp/bake/blob/1.2.3/src/Shell/Task/TemplateTask.php#L301-L312**
- **https://github.com/cakephp/bake/blob/1.2.3/src/Shell/Task/ControllerTask.php#L138**

This is something for a feature request that you could issue [**over at GitHub**](https://github.com/cakephp/bake/issues), or you could even push a PR yourself.

If you can't wait for this to be implemented, you could create your own extended bake command, ie extend the template task, overwrite `TemplateTask::_loadController()`, and add the prefix (`TemplateTask::_getPrefix()`) to the returned array, something along the lines of

```
<?php
namespace App\Shell\Task;

use Bake\Shell\Task\TemplateTask;

class MyTemplateTask extends TemplateTask
{
    protected function _loadController()
    {
        return parent::_loadController() + [
            'prefix' => $this->_getPrefix()
        ];
    }
}
```

The value should then be available as `$prefix` in your bake template.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Bake Console > Extending Bake > Creating New Bake Command Options](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/development.html#creating-new-bake-command-options)**